# How to get result from window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am using window.location.href="http://www.xxxx.com/app/getUser?code=2019"
send it to backend and backend returned result !
But there is no callback function from window.location.href, so how to get the result?

Comment: The result is a new page send by the server.

Comment: What you're looking for is `ajax` calls.

Comment: You'll want to use something like `fetch(url).then(response => { console.log(response); });` (what you're doing causes the browser to navigate there)

Comment: I need to show authorization page to get parameter from authorization url,
using window.location.href can get the parameter but using ajax can open new page to get it

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a new value to `location.href` causes the browser to navigate to a new page.

This causes the browser to leave the previous page which destroys the execution environment the JavaScript would be running in.

The new page creates its own execution environment. If you want to run JavaScript in it, then you can simply use a script element.

```
<script>  alert("the page is loading"); </script>
```

… you could combine this with a DOM Ready or Load event listener.

Answer (score 0):

The window.location.href function just redirects to a given url.If you want the result in the same page you have to use AJAX. for example the following code will give you results returned by the server in text format

```
var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
{var result=xmlhttp.responseText; //This is the result returned by the server
dosomething(result);
 } 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "your url", true); 
 xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: I want to change the current page from "www.test.com/?code=123" to "www.test.com/?code=123&name=mike", using window.location.href can help me but ajax seems not to work

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood your question

Comment: But your original question clearly differs from what you are mentioning here.Please be clear on what you want to achieve